# "svn: Syntax error in revision argument" for date formats

Tags: svn, date, syntax, formats

Can anybody tell me using svn on OS 10.7.3 with a **tcsh** shell what date formats are accepted?  I'm attempting to do an `svn up -r {DATE}` and every time I get this:

```
svn: Syntax error in revision argument
```

The formats described here are not accepted:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.tour.revs.html

My last attempt was to try an checkout:

```
svn checkout --revision {2012-02-17} svn+ssh://blah/blah blah
svn: Syntax error in revision argument '2012-02-17'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**tcsh** is different than **bash** in this regard: the issue is the curly braces.

Try:

```
svn checkout --revision \{2012-02-17\} svn+ssh://blah/blah blah
```